# Multiple timeseries data Anomaly detection

Tags: python, autoencoder, outliers, anomaly-detection, data-preprocessing

First, Im so sorry about that I can not show you a data by image
it is because this is my company computer which have some security system
I have some data looks like

```
         Time_1, Time_2, Time_3 ... Time_n  label
```

production_1   123    125                          0
production_2   121    131                          1
production_3   129    130                          0
production_4   121    120                          0
'
'
'
production_n                                      0

in this case I want to find Abnomal data(label=1) not an abnormal point.
I can't find some example like this. What can I do for this problem?

Well, I did normal, abnormal split(with row) and then Standard scailing and using PYOD KNN Model and autoencoder
but the score is very low. So I thought, I should find new way to preprocessing my data, and model
If you have any Idea,,,please help me.

in many github and website just finding an abnormal point at one time series data, but I have different format data, so I think that would be an specific way to control this situation

Comment: Use a reconstructing autoencoder (RNN/CNN) trained on the time-series, with training set consisting only on normal data.

Comment: I try to doing Conv1d AE, but im not sure that Conv1d AE model contain the meaning of timeseries. is the conv1d AE contaim the meaning of timeseriese?

Comment: Yes - though it depends on how the layers are set up. Need to make sure the receptive field at input is large enough, and that the temporal resolution at output is suitable